# Shallow copy dict while overriding a key value pair using python

Tags: python, dictionary, copy, key-value

I'm trying to copy a dict while simultaneously over riding one of the key value pairs while performing the copy. I thought something like this was possible, but this doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

```
a_dict = {'foo' : 'bar', 'bah' : 'baz'}
b_dict = dict(a_dict, 'foo' : 'cat' )

desired result of b_dict = {'foo' : 'cat', 'bah' : 'baz'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do it in two steps:

```
b_dict = dict(a_dict)
b_dict["foo"] = "cat"
```

You could also do it in one step using a dict comprehension:

```
b_dict = {key: "cat" if key == "foo" else value for key, value in a_dict.iteritems()}
```

but it won't be as efficient for a very large dictionary.

Comment: Yes, I should've added I am currently doing it in two steps, but thought python had a way of easily doing during the copy operation. Appreciate your dict comprehension answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
b_dict = dict(a_dict, foo='cat')
```

or

```
b_dict = dict(a_dict, **{'foo': 'cat'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `copy` is better way.

```
a_dict = {'foo' : 'bar', 'bah' : 'baz'}
b_dict = a_dict.copy()
b_dict.update({'foo' : 'cat'})

print(b_dict)   #  {'bah': 'baz', 'foo': 'cat'}
print(a_dict)   #  {'bah': 'baz', 'foo': 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
b_dict = dict(list(a_dict.items()) + [('foo', 'cat')])
```

Some might prefer this variation:

```
b_dict = dict(list(a_dict.items()) + list(dict(foo='cat').items()))
```